# System.Exception: Did not find MSBuild for runtime Mono

Tags: macos, build, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, monodevelop

I'm compiling the sources in Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac and I've got the following error:

```
Building: ServiceLayer.API (Debug)
Error: Build failed. See the build log for details. (ServiceLayer.API)
---------------------- Done ----------------------
Build failed.
Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

In `Ide.log` log file, I've the following entry:

```
ERROR [2017-10-08 20:20:45Z]: Inspector does not support this project type
ERROR [2017-10-08 20:20:45Z]: Build failed.
System.Exception: Did not find MSBuild for runtime Mono 4.0.2 (c99aa0c)
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectService.GetNewestInstalledToolsVersion (MonoDevelop.Core.Assemblies.TargetRuntime runtime, System.Boolean requiresMicrosoftBuild, System.String& binDir) [0x0006e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/cab57de4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects.MSBuild/MSBuildProjectService.cs:1087 
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectService+<GetProjectBuilder>d__100.MoveNext () [0x00133] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/cab57de4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects.MSBuild/MSBuildProjectService.cs:1116
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:151 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4992/mono-mac-sdk/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357
  at MonoDevelop.Projects.Project+<GetProjectBuilder>d__157.MoveNext () [0x001bb] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5144/cab57de4/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects/Project.cs:1418 
...
ERROR [2017-10-08 20:21:16Z]: An unhandled exception has occured. Terminating Visual Studio? False
```

<sup>Notes: In total like 381 lines on each attempt to build. 'End of stack trace' line is repeated 52 times.</sup>

This pointed me to this line in *MonoDevelop* (see: [`MSBuildProjectService.cs`](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Projects.MSBuild/MSBuildProjectService.cs#L1086)):

```
throw new Exception ("Did not find MSBuild for runtime " + runtime.Id);
```

I've checked and `msbuild` command exist in the command-line:

```
$ which msbuild
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/msbuild
$ msbuild --version
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.4.0.0 (master/f296e67b Thu Sep 21 19:38:16 EDT 2017) for Mono
$ stat /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current
  File: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.0
```

What I've tried so far:

- I've tested both channels (*Stable* and *Beta*) in *Visual Studio Update* without success.
- I've tried to *Clean All* and *Rebuild All*.
- I've tried to remove the cache files in `~/Library/Caches/VisualStudio`.
- Reinstalling VisualStudio.

I've checked in *Visual Studio*, *Preference...*, *Projects*, *.NET Runtimes* and I've the latest *Mono* set as *Default* (to 5.4.x):

[image: Mono, *Visual Studio*, *Preference...*, *Projects*, *.NET Runtimes*]

However when debugging, it's trying to open `msbuild` for 4.0.2 instead, e.g.:

```
$ sudo fs_usage -f pathname VisualStudio | grep -i msbuild
12:34:38  stat64            /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.2/lib/mono/msbuild>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    0.000007   VisualStudio
12:34:38  lstat64           /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.2/lib/mono/msbuild>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    0.000002   VisualStudio
12:34:38  access            /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.2/lib/mono/msbuild>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    0.000002   VisualStudio
```

which doesn't exist.

---

How should I add a missing *MSBuild* to my *Solution* (project) (as per mentioned error)?

Comment: What is your project type? Is desktop framework? How about this issue for a new blank c# project, like class library?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT It's a service API framework which handles the APIs from the web app and talks to the payment system. It works on Windows slave when build from Jenkins, so basically I'm trying to debug it on my local, but VS basically stopped working properly for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono 4.0.2 did not have `msbuild`, it was included in 4.8.0+ . Check where does `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current` (symlink) point to. It probably points to some mono 5.x.y . Try changing the .NET runtime that VSMac is set to use in *Preferences -> Projects -> .NET Runtimes*, to the latest one.

For some reason it is still looking it in 4.0.2. I would try to, at least temporarily, remove that 4.0.2 directory and then check. But otherwise I think your installation is broken and I would try to reinstall the whole thing (VSMac, Mono, ..).

Also, check in your `Ide.log` file for any references to 4.0.2, before that exception.

If you run into the same issue even with a fresh install, then please file a bug at [bugzilla.xamarin.com](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/) and we can try to debug it there.

Comment: `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current -> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.0`

Comment: In _Preferences_ I've already the latest one, which is 5.4.0.201

Comment: For some reason it is still looking in `4.0.2`. I would try to, at least temporarily, remove that `4.0.2` directory and then check. But otherwise I think your installation is broken and I would try to reinstall the whole thing (VSMac, Mono, ..) . If you run into the same issue even with a fresh install, then please file a bug at https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/ and we can try to debug it there.

Comment: Also, in your Ide.log do you see any reference to `4.0.2` before that exception? sharing that log file should be useful too.

Comment: Reported issue at [#60103](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60103), I've attached the log file there (you can check), but there is nothing obvious. I'll also try to debug this further soon. What's clear now, somehow VC incorrectly looking for `msbuild` binary inside `4.0.2` folder (see my edit).